# bip irc proxy and client disconnects

Tags: proxy, irc, irc-bouncer

Currently, a `bip` instance I've configured connects to the prescribed network(s), and allows a connection from a client through SSL (offering the self-signed cert).  However, after connection is established, the client(s) is immediately disconnected "by peer."

This lead me to believe that the problem was with the user password, but it doesn't appear to be the case as I've tested generating and using the password `test` with `bipmkpw`.  I've also attempted to connect with SSL disabled, and the same remote disconnection occurs.

The bip.conf is as follows:

```
# vim:ft=bip:ts=2
# Auto-generated BIP IRC Proxy configuration Sun Dec  1 22:55:45 2013
#
### Global options
log_system = false;
client_side_ssl_pem = "/root/.bip/bip.pem";
ip = "0.0.0.0";
log_sync_interval = 5;
port = 7778;
log_format = "%n/%Y-%m/%c.%d.log";
pid_file = "/root/.bip/bip.pid";
log_level = 2;
log_root = "/root/.bip/logs";
client_side_ssl = true;
log = true;

### Networks
network {
        name = "freenode";
        ssl = true;
        server {
                host = "chat.freenode.net";
                port = 7000;
        };

};


### Users
user {
        name = "mbrown";
        password = "hashyhashy";
        ssl_check_mode = "none";
        default_nick = "mbrownnyc";
        default_user = "mbrownnyc";
        default_realname = "matt";
        backlog = true;
        connection {
                name = "freenode";
                network = "freenode";
                follow_nick = true;
                ignore_first_nick = true;
                ssl_check_mode = "none";
                channel {
                        name = "#bip";
                };

        };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I chatted with a dev on IRC, and he advised me to use the following combination for the password: `user:password:connection`

For instance, given the above `bip` config I would configure a connection as follows:

user: mbrown
password: mbrown:thisisthepasswordthatproducesahash:freenode

Only if "hashyhashy" is the hash produced by "thisisthepasswordthatproducesahash".

As noted much more elegantly in [the man](https://projects.duckcorp.org/projects/bip/repository/entry/README):

```
CONNECTING YOUR CLIENT(S)

Then you want to use your regular irc client and connect to bip.  Point

your client to the machine bip is running and set the proper port number

(defined in your bip.conf). You should then configure the client to use a

specific irc server password constructed this way:



user:password:connection



The user is the name field of the "user" section, the password is the

password (*not* the hash) corresponding to the "password" field of the

same user section (which is the hash generated with bipmkpw) and the

connection is the "name" field of the "connection" subsection. This is

how bip authenticates you and puts your client to the correct network.



Using the default (or sample file) configuration, logs are in ~/.bip/logs/
```